# Angularjs Smart Table responsive table

Tags: angularjs, html, responsive-design, datatables, smart-table

I viewed all the examples in the smart table website http://lorenzofox3.github.io/smart-table-website/ and looked the plunkers but I couldn't find any responsive examples where the columns hide like in this datatables example where a "plus" sign appears when the sceen gets small like in this example https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/withResponsive, I tried the examples in the smart table website but when I shrink the screen the table becomes unreadable and I didn't shrink the screen to much just a little I tried with this example https://plnkr.co/edit/fcdXKE?p=preview

```
angular.module('myApp', ['smart-table'])
.controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

    var
        nameList = ['Pierre', 'Pol', 'Jacques', 'Robert', 'Elisa'],
        familyName = ['Dupont', 'Germain', 'Delcourt', 'bjip', 'Menez'];

    function createRandomItem() {
        var
            firstName = nameList[Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)],
            lastName = familyName[Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)],
            age = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100),
            email = firstName + lastName + '@whatever.com',
            balance = Math.random() * 3000;

        return{
            firstName: firstName,
            lastName: lastName,
            age: age,
            email: email,
            balance: balance
        };
    }


    $scope.displayed = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < 50; j++) {
        $scope.displayed.push(createRandomItem());
    }
}])
.directive('stRatio',function(){
    return {
      link:function(scope, element, attr){
        var ratio=+(attr.stRatio);

        element.css('width',ratio+'%');

      }
    };
});
```

Is there a way to make those plus signs appears or somehitng similar to make the table really responsive?

Comment: Can use media queries to hide less important columns and show icon that can be used  to display  modal with full details

Comment: do you have a example of what you told me , also if you look at this example https://plnkr.co/edit/fcdXKE?p=preview and you choose the responsive option in firefox or chrome and you put the device with a size of 250x365 the table becomes unreadable all the text gets collapsed, it's there a way at least to put a scroller bar at the bottom

Comment: Not off hand but using css media queries and classes on columns  it's relatively easy to create. Show the icon/button column on small screens nd hide the non critical columns

Comment: As for scroll  bar that's simple too if you wrap in parent div with overflow css set and `min-width` on table